# JavaScript: Create new array from non-sequential existing array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I have

```
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
```

I want to create a new array, arr2, consisting of elements from indices 1 and 4 of arr1.
I have looked at slice() but it only works in sequence. Is there an existing method I am missing or do I have to create one?
Thanks.

Comment: The question is not clear, what do you mean by non sequential ?

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: please add the wanted result and what you have tried

Comment: `arr2.push(arr1[0]);arr2.push(arr1[4]);`

Comment: Accepting @Nina's. And the example should have read 1 and 4 not 1 and 5. I have fixed that now.Thanks for all the suggestions. Very much appreciated

Comment: Not sure why this is on hold. I got multiple valid answers and chose the one that suited best.

Comment: I wanted to create a new array using some elements from an existing array. I could not find a built-in method to do this and asked for help. Maybe I shouldn't have mentioned creating a method? Anyway, happy with the solution and appreciative of the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the wanted indices as array and map the values.

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    indices = [1, 4],
    result = indices.map(i => array[i]);
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wonder if OP meant Index #5 or 5th item?

Comment: @mplungjan: The OP specifically said "indices 1 and 5". But yes, he/she probably meant 0 and 4. :-)

Answer (score 5):

> I want to create a new array, arr2, consisting of elements from indices 1 and 5 of arr1

That's simple, no need for a method, just literal notation:

```
var arr2 = [arr1[1], arr1[5]];
```

(I should note that you have no "index 5" in your array. Did you mean indices 0 and 4?)

Live Example (using 1 and 5):

```js
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
var arr2 = [arr1[1], arr1[5]];
console.log(arr2);
```

Live Example (using 0 and 4):

```js
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
var arr2 = [arr1[0], arr1[4]];
console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: @Rajesh OP did say index at `5`. Not `4`

Answer (score 2):

Just assign them?

```js
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
var arr2 = [arr1[0],arr1[4]];

console.log(arr1)
console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: Was going that route but wanted something faster. Going to go with @Nina's suggestion but acknowledge that if non-sequential then will have to address individually somewhere.Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this:

```js
    var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
    var arr2 = arr1.filter((it, index) => index === 0 || index === 4);
    console.log(arr2);
```